# Libgdx : setting another screen, but still buttons from old screen active

Tags: java, android, libgdx

In my libgdx `game`, I have 2 screens, `menu` and `list`.
When I click on a `label` in the `menu` screen, I do a `setscreen(list)`.
The new screen shows up, and the menu screen alongwith its labels disappears.

But when I click on the same positions (from menu screen where the labels were, but of course those labels are not showing as I have changed screens) the click event responds. Why?

note:My list screen currently has not event handlers for any widget.

When switching screens do I need to do anything more than just `setscreen(anotherscreen)` to deactivate oldscreen?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I changed this :

I moved the input processor to the show() method of that screen using stage variable of that screen

```
public void show() {
    ...
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

}
```

before I was setting this only in the constructor of the screen, so even If I was changing the screen, the input processor was still attached to the last created screen's stage

Comment: This worked for me. Can you give a little explanation how this works together and why?

Answer (score 3):

The answer above adiddnt work for me because I dont work with a InputProcessor in the 2nd screen.

My Solution was to set the Inputprocessor to null after setScreen.

`Gdx.app.getApplicationListener().setScreen(new Screen());
 Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(null);`

Answer (score 0):

Just broke my head over this. I changed screens in the `show` method but had `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage)` called after that. The method still completed after the `show` method of the new screen ran and thus reverting back to the previous stage.

So make sure you call `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage)` before you change screens or `return` after you change screens.