# libGDX: "Ghost" button on next screen after setting screen

Tags: java, android, libgdx

It's almost the same problem like this question, but it doesn't work for me: [Libgdx : setting another screen, but still buttons from old screen active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18170274/libgdx-setting-another-screen-but-still-buttons-from-old-screen-active)

First Screen:

```
 public void show(){
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    myButton.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            game.setScreen(new SecondScreen(game));
            dispose();
            return;
        }
    });

 public void dispose(){
    stage.dispose();
 }
```

Second Screen:

```
public void show(){
   Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
   [...]
}
```

After setting a new screen I can still see the buttons from my first screen with an opacity of ~20%. It's like a "ghost" button. What's the reason for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try stage.clear() and clear the screen with the gl method before you switch screens.

Answer (score 0):

Do you clear the screen in render() method in SecondScreen class?

```
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Comment: Yes, I do. First clear the screen and then stage.act() and stage.draw()

Comment: You would probably need to post her complete but simplified code (both screen classes) as proof of error.